# Repeating background in cocos2d has black edges!

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, background-image

I am attempting to setup a tiled/repeating background for my iPhone app.

The code "works" in that the background is repeating like it should be but I seem to have a black border around each repetition and I dont know why, the image is exactly 200x200.  Here is a screenshot of how it looks along with the code:

```
if ((self=[super init])) {
    CCSprite * bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pattern11.jpg" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 520)];
    [bg setPosition:ccp(0, 0)];
    ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_REPEAT};
    [bg.texture setTexParameters:&params];
    [self addChild:bg z:0];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Textures should always be in power of two... like 16,32,64,128,256,512,1024.

Try resizing the image to 256x256 or 128x128.

Answer (score 0):

I've also ran across this rather common problem with not being able to tile arbitrarily-sized textures in Cocos2d-iPhone, so I put together a simple TiledSprite class to tile/clip a texture or subtexture to any width/height.

Jump right to the source code here (use at will):

https://gist.github.com/Nolithius/6694990

Or have a look at a usage sample, screenshot, and commentary in this brief article:

http://www.nolithius.com/game-development/cocos2d-iphone-repeating-sprite

Best of luck!